# Redirected output hangs when using tee

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I'd like to provide an optional logging parameter in a bash script, and would like to use `exec` to `tee` a pipe from the beginning.  However, opening the `tee` process is causing the script to hang, I believe because stdout is not closed:

```
# Output to a log file, if set
if [[ $OPT_LOG ]]; then
    exec > >(tee -a $OPT_LOG)
fi
```

I've attempted to close with:

```
exec >&-
```

But it still hangs - is there another way to properly close `tee` so the script will exit properly at the end of execution?

Comment: This code (liberally sprinkled with semicolons so it can be copied and pasted from this comment) exits OK for me on Mac OS X 10.10.3.  `OPT_LOG=file.name;
if [[ $OPT_LOG ]]; then exec > >(tee -a $OPT_LOG); fi;
for ((i = 0; i < 10; i++));
do echo "Logging message $i at $(date)"; sleep 1;
done` (the only semicolon in my original was the one before `then`, and that only because I copied the code from the question — it's not how I write shell scripts). Your problem is probably in the code you've not shown. What commands are you running? What do you get from `bash -x yourscript.sh`?

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: If removing `sleep` and `date` calls from your example, the script no more exits properly, as told by Andrew: `OPT_LOG=file.name; if [[ $OPT_LOG ]]; then exec > >(tee -a $OPT_LOG); fi; for ((i = 0; i < 10; i++)); do echo "Logging message $i"; done`

Comment: @chatraed: Now that's an interesting observation!  I can reproduce your result.  I experimented a bit.  I added a `pwd` before the `for` loop with 'just the echo', and that didn't affect things (but `pwd` is probably a built-in).  I added `bash -c 'exit 0'` (which is not a built-in) and the code terminated OK. I tried using `> >(tee -a $OPT_LOG &)` and the output didn't appear (I'm moderately convinced it should have appeared, but Bash seems to want it to behave otherwise.) My impression is that Andrew has found a bug in Bash that could viably be reported; I don't think that not exiting is OK.

Comment: @chatraed: it also confirms that your workaround works, albeit more slowly than minimally necessary.  For production use, I'd choose something faster than sleeping for any length of time — other than perhaps `sleep 0` which should be good and fast.  It is also relatively unusual that a shell script does not invoke any external command, and invoking any external command after the `exec` redirection seems to suppress the bug.

Comment: Oh, and I over-claimed on the absence of semicolons in my original script; the `for ((i = 0; i < 10; i++))` line needed the two semicolons, of course.

Answer (score 6):

It seems like, for some reason, using `tee` stops the prompt (`$PS1`) from appearing because the shell script has not exited. As a workaround, I generally use a short `sleep` after calling `tee`.

```
#!/bin/bash

exec > >(tee -a mylog)
sleep .1
# my code
```

Comment: I just spent 3 hours trying to figure out why my shell script hangs. You saved my night. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

<sup>*Converting comments into an answer, with minor edits.*</sup>

I [noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30687504/redirected-output-hangs-when-using-tee?noredirect=1#comment49438306_30687504):

> The following code exits OK for me on Mac OS X 10.10.3.
>
> ```
> OPT_LOG=file.name
> if [[ $OPT_LOG ]]
> then exec > >(tee -a $OPT_LOG)
> fi
> for ((i = 0; i < 10; i++))
> do
>     echo "Logging message $i at $(date)"
>     sleep 1
> done
> ```
>
> Your problem is probably in the code you've not shown. What commands are you running? What do you get from `bash -x yourscript.sh`?

And [chatraed](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2381750/chatraed) [observed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30687504/redirected-output-hangs-when-using-tee?noredirect=1#comment49441701_30687504)

> If you remove the sleep and date calls from your example, the script does not exit properly any more, as told by Andrew:
>
> ```
> OPT_LOG=file.name;
> if [[ $OPT_LOG ]]; then exec > >(tee -a $OPT_LOG); fi;
> for ((i = 0; i < 10; i++)); do echo "Logging message $i"; done
> ```

And I responded:

> Now that's an interesting observation! I can reproduce your result.

I experimented a bit:

- I added a `pwd` before the for loop with 'just the echo', and that didn't affect things (but `pwd` is probably a Bash built-in).
- I added `bash -c 'exit 0'` (which is not a built-in) and the code terminated OK.
- I tried using `> >(tee -a $OPT_LOG &)` and the output didn't appear — on screen or in the file. (I find this surprising, but it was an attempted workaround, not a major part of the work.)

My impression is that Andrew has found a bug in Bash that could viably be reported. (See the Bash manual on [Reporting Bugs](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Reporting-Bugs) for how to do that.)  I don't think that not exiting simply because no external commands have been executed since the I/O redirection is OK.  I can confirm that Apple's Bash 3.2.57 has the problem; so does Bash 4.3.27 (which I built for myself so it is patched with the fixes to the [ShellShock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shellshock_%28software_bug%29) bug).

It is relatively unusual that a shell script does not invoke any external command, and invoking any external command after the exec redirection seems to suppress the bug.

It also confirms that [chatraed](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2381750/chatraed)'s [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30687854/15168) works, albeit more slowly than minimally necessary. For production use, I'd choose `sleep 0`, which is most of a tenth of a second faster than `sleep 0.1`.  And sleeping for a fraction of a second only works on some systems; classically (and according to POSIX), [`sleep`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sleep.html) does not sleep for fractional seconds.  OTOH, if you write `sleep 0.1`, on systems without support for fractional seconds, including the leading `0` probably makes it sleep for zero seconds anyway; writing `.1` might or might not have the same effect.

Comment: Good findings and sum-up!

Comment: The next step would probably be extracting the list of shell builtins with `help` and checking if the behavior is consistent with all of them.

Comment: Is there a Bash bug report for this issue?

Comment: @SteveAmerige — I have no recollection of filing one.  I have not checked whether it is still a problem in 2021.